# How to call web service interface by ESB way

Tags: c#, web-services

I used to call interface by adding service reference directly(C# project), like following example

```
ServiceReference1.ExampleClient eClient  = new ServiceReference1.ExampleClient();
eClient.GetInfo(ref status,ref count,ref msg);
....
```

but now they registered in ESB and I can't use webservice directly, and following sample code is about ESB registering

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
...
//Operations to add headers for client ESB register information
...
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(ExampleUrl).Result;
```

so how could I pass the parameters and call the interface(like eClent.GetInfo) using the second method instead of adding service reference directly?
Is anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a `GET` request the parameters will go in the url or in the headers or both. Hopefully the documentation is clear on that.

```
//You should share this instance, don't new it up every request
```

[see this](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/07/01/using-httpclient-as-it-was-intended-because-youre-not/)

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

//Craft the URL
string urlWithParams = $"{ExampleUrl}?status={status}&count={count}&msg={msg}";

//Await the response DO NOT USE .Result !
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(urlWithParams);

//Read the response content. I'm assuming it is JSON format so you can read
//it as a string but consult the documentation.
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

//Now you can deserialize to a class if you need/want to.
//Assume you have a class `Foo` that has properties matching the response JSON.
//And also assuming you have a reference to JSON.Net
Foo theFoo = JsonConvert.DerserializeObject<Foo>(result);
```

Note how I used `await` for async calls. If you use `.Result` (does the documentation really have that? That's irresponsible) then you will probably be back here asking why your calls never return. Use a synchronous API like `HttpWebRequest` instead of `HttpClient` if you are not able to use async in your code base.

If the response is XML instead of JSON then you can read it into an `XDocument` or use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize it into a `Foo`. I've been as specific as I could with the limited information, hopefully this gets you going.