# Automatically create Vendor on other system based on new Vendor creation on Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am new to Acumatica integration and need advice about how to automatically trigger Vendor creation on other system right after user create the same data on Acumatica. I've been try to understand I210_ContractBasedWebServices_6 training material and as far as I know that to trigger the data creation, I need to override Persist method on VendorMaint graph and add some line to call API controller and still do not know whether it is the best way to do or not.

I also still need to know about how to configure the connectivity between the two system. The other system is build on Java and using Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) and Service Adapter to communicate with external system. The web service is also available but not frequently used. If I am going to develop the API controller on C#, how can I communicate to that ESB and Service Adapter so I can trigger Vendor Creation on other System? Kindly need advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed, you can use the BLC Persist method or the Vendor DAC RowPersisted event handler to accomplish that.

The Vendor screen in Acumatica allows the user to insert a vendor basic information and fill in the details later. To properly sync between the two systems you'll need to customize this screen to make all the desired fields required so they're filled in on vendor creation or you can also handle the case when the user updates the vendor instead of inserting.

Since we can predict that the Web Service call can take some time to execute we can wrap it in a PXLongOperation delegate. This will display a wait indicator in the top right of the web page on long operation.

```
public class VendorMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<VendorMaint>
{
  public virtual void Vendor_RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
  {
    Vendor vendor = e.Row as Vendor;

    if (vendor != null &&
        e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Insert &&
        e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
    {        
      PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate()
      {
        // Add your webservice call here
      });
    }
  }
}
```

From this answer:
[How to call web service interface by ESB way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976656/how-to-call-web-service-interface-by-esb-way)
 it appears ESB Web Service are as vanilla as it gets so you can consume them with .Net Framework HttpClient Class. You want to write a C# ESB Web Service Client. There's nothing particular in Acumatica about writing Web Service client so you can follow general advice for doing so in C#.